# Cordova Android camera permission fires Camera-JNI and Buffer Queue non-stop preventing app from sleeping

Tags: android, cordova

Has anyone see this in the logs, once the app loads the following fires off until you close the app, preventing it from sleeping. (Only attached a small clip but it just keeps repeating this until you close the app.)

```
11710   D   Camera-JNI   Using callback buffer from queue of length 3 
11633   -   I   CameraFramework  handleMessage: 16 
11633   -   D   Camera-JNI   Adding callback buffer to queue, 3 total 
11658   I   BufferQueueProducer  [unnamed-11633-0](this:0xef0c7c00,id:0,api:4,p:290,c:11633) queueBuffer: slot 6 is dropped, handle=0xd67aa660 
11633   11710   D   Camera-JNI   Using callback buffer from queue of length 3 
11633   -   I   CameraFramework  handleMessage: 16 
11633   -   D   Camera-JNI   Adding callback buffer to queue, 3 total 
11633   11658   I   BufferQueueProducer  [unnamed-11633-0](this:0xef0c7c00,id:0,api:4,p:290,c:11633) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0xdbc50d80 
11633   11710   D   Camera-JNI   Using callback buffer from queue of length 3 
11633   -   I   CameraFramework  handleMessage: 16 
11633   -   D   Camera-JNI   Adding callback buffer to queue, 3 total
```

Using Cordova version 6.2.0 with Cordova android version 5.1.1
Happens with or without the use of plugins.
The only way I have found to stop it is to not include the android camera permission.